# Entity Framework 6 Code First Migration not working with Oracle Database

Tags: entity-framework, oracle11g, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with EF6 and Oracle database.

I am using the code First approach, I created my entities and My Context class and then I tried the `Enable and Add a Migration` but I got this error.

However, If I use SQL SERVER in the place of Oracle database it works fine but not with Oracle database.

This is the error:

> ```
> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred accessing the database. 
> This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate
> ```
>
> DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the
>   application's config file. 
>       See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. 
>       See the inner exception for details of the failure. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider
>   did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. --->
>       Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-12154: TNS : impossible de résoudre l'identificateur de connexion indiqué --->
>   OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException: ORA-12154: TNS : impossible
>   de résoudre l'identificateur de connexion indiqué
>          at OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution..ctor(String TNSAlias, String instanceName)
>          at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
>          at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Connect(String tnsDescriptor, Boolean doNAHandshake, String IName)
>          at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString
>   cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria,
>   String instanceName)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString
>   csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection
>   connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
>          at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString
>   csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection
>   connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
>          at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString
>   cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword,
>   SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection
>   connRefForCriteria)
>          at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
>          at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`3
>   k)
>          at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection
>   connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext
>   context, XmlWriter writer)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(XmlWriter
>   w)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1
>   writeXml)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext
>   context)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   migrationsConfiguration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>       An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection
>   string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is
>   being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file.
>   See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on
>   DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the
>   failure*.

And this is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BiatContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=SYSTEM;Password=admin;Data Source=oracle" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Getting similar exception. Any help

Answer (score 0):

You must change your connection string like this

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="BiatContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=SYSTEM;Password=admin; Min Pool Size=20; Max Pool Size=200; Connection Lifetime=120;Connection Timeout=70;Incr Pool Size=2; Decr Pool Size=3;Data Source=oracle" />
</connectionStrings>
```